# Python convention for variables that won't be used, but are reuturned from a function nonetheless

Tags: python, convention

If I have a function like the following:

```
def foo():
    return 1, 2
```

I would normally call the function like:

```
g, f = foo()
```

But if I never plan on using the second value returned, is there a way of calling the function that makes that clear, so in the future I won't get distracted by a place-filler variable?

For example, something like:

```
g, not_used = foo()
```

Seems like there's probably a standard way to do this that is out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could get the first item directly:

```
g = foo()[0]
```

I think [pylint recommends `_` or `dummy`](http://www.logilab.org/card/pylintfeatures#id9):

```
g, _ = foo()
```

Comment: Thanks for the pylint reference. It was indeed what prompted this question.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just ask for the index of the value I care about

```
g = foo()[0]
```

Comment: This is fine for simple cases, but doesn't generalize all that well.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, that's true... and '_' is a good solution.  I've just not seen it in much python code I've been around.  Also, if your function would return a tuple of more than two items, it's usually an indication you may be able to refactor (especially if you only care about one of the return values).